# What does "use of class template requires template argument list" mean?

Tags: c++, templates

I am a newbie to templates so please excuse me for naive questions. I'm getting errors in this code:

```
template <class t>
class a{
public:
    int i;
    a(t& ii):i(ii){}
};


int main()
{
    a *a1(new a(3));
    cout<<a1.i;

    _getch();
}
```

Compile errors:

1. `'a' : use of class template requires template argument list`
2. `'a' : class has no constructors`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a(t& ii):i(ii){}
```

This should be :

```
a(const t& ii):i(ii){}
```

So that you can pass const literals, and temporaries to the constructor.

And then do this:

```
a<int> *a1(new a<int>(3));
```

You can also write:

```
a<int> a2(3);
```

Comment: You have the wrong type in the template. It should definitely be `a<FooBar> *a1(new a<FooBar>(3));` Just make sure Foo bar is convertible to int.

Comment: Joking. :-) Its just that T seemed relatively useless. What ever type it was is being converted to int in the consrtuctor. Why not convert it to int as it is passed to the parameter. Hence `FooBar`

Answer (score 9):

Use

```
a<int> *a1(new a<int>(3));
 ^^^^^          ^^^^
```

If you want your template parameter to be automatically deduced, you can use a helper function:

```
template<class T>
a<T> * createA (const T& arg) //please add const to your ctor, too.
{
    return new a<T>(arg)
}
```